# Rookie cannot upload txt file with php

Tags: php

I am using the following   php  file,

result

```
Upload: test.com.html
Type: text/html
Size: 135.921875 kB
Stored in: /tmp/phpA8DGdB
Possible file upload attack! 

Here is some more debugging info:
    Array ( 
          [file] => 
             Array ( 
                    [name] => test.com.html
                    [type] => text/html 
                    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpA8DGdB 
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 139184 
         ) 

    )
```

PHP FILE:-

```
 <?php
 if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
 {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
 }
 else
 {
   echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
   echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
   echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
   echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
 }
 $uploaddir = '/var/www/setup/upload';
 $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

 echo '<pre>';
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
 echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
 } else {
 echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
 }
 echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
 print_r($_FILES);
 print "</pre>";
 ?>
```

So, I cannot upload file. I would appreciate any hint , Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: result      

 Upload:test.com.html
    Type: text/html
    Size: 135.921875 kB
    Stored in: /tmp/phpA8DGdB
  Possible file upload attack!
  Here is some more debugging info:Array
 (
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => test.com.html
            [type] => text/html
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpA8DGdB
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 139184
        )

  )

Comment: Add that to the question so it's readable.

Comment: I was put in the question but, unfortunately, I had a message (something like) “too much code,  You cannot submit please add more comment ”    :-(

Comment: 1. add the error msg 2. have a close look at contents of `$uploadfile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a directory separator between `$uploaddir` and the filename:

```
$uploaddir = '/var/www/setup/upload/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
```

Comment: Oops... typo, I make the correction [thank you]

 but still not working...

Comment: What error is `move_uploaded_file` reporting?

Comment: I found it !!!  web server has not permissions!! to the directory !! Thank you!!